# Working in monorepo with React Client and deno in vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, deno, supabase

I am new to Supabase and deno

Have anyone worked with supabase in mono-repo? My client is react and edge functions is  deno.

Enabling deno plugin, makes VScode not complete import statements, command-click, and so on in react.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deno.enablePaths` in your `.vscode/settings.json` file to limit which paths in your workspace should use the Deno Language Server:

```json
{
  "deno.enable": true,
  "deno.enablePaths": ["./path/to/edge/functions"]
}
```

You can specify more than one path if necessary. This will change the behavior with import statements, etc. in only those paths and their subpaths.